extra fields in $text error when doing a text search on a mongoose collection
I have indexes setup on customer schema like below
CustomerSchema.index({ firstName: 1, dob: 1 });
CustomerSchema.index({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1, dob: 1 });
CustomerSchema.index({
  firstName: 'text',
  lastName: 'text',
  primaryPhone: 'text',
  primaryEmail: 'text',
  masterId: 'text',
  'sourceIds.id': 'text',
});
CustomerSchema.index({ lastName: 1, dob: 1 });
CustomerSchema.index({ 'phones.value': 1, 'phones.type': 1 });

export const Customers = mongoose.model('customers', CustomerSchema);

I have a search functionality in the frontend and this is what we are doing for the search functionality in the backend , we are using node and mongoose
if (searchQuery) {
          q.push({
            $match: {
              $or: [
                { primaryPhone: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
                { primaryEmail: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
                { 'sourceIds.id': { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
                { firstName: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
                { lastName: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
                { masterId: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
              ],
            },
          });
        }

Couple of issues with the above code

It's using regex so performance is slow
when the search query is "Karthik surya" it does not match the records where firstName is "Karthik"

so for the reasons mentioned above I decided to use text search and changed the code to below
if (searchQuery) {
          q.push({
            $match: {
              $text: {
                $search: searchQuery,
                $path: [
                  'primaryPhone',
                  'primaryEmail',
                  'sourceIds.id',
                  'firstName',
                  'lastName',
                  'masterId',
                ],
              },
            },
          });
        }


so when the query is executed I am getting the following error
 MongoServerError: extra fields in $text
        at Connection.onMessage (C:\guardian-group\c360-customers\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:421:18)
        at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\guardian-group\c360-customers\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:251:56)

what am i doing wrong ? and is there a better way to achieve this? should i use a search index provided by atlas?

The usage of $text search with $path is only available on MongoDB Atlas. Also, it doesn't need to be in a $match stage, from the linked Atlas example.

@aneroid if i remove it from match stage I am getting an error

As I said, that's for Atlas. Is your DB on Atlas? If you're not on Atlas then (a) You can't use $path and (b) $text must be within a $match (which you've done)
